# How to handle and prompt file name during file save (Word 2016, VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, save-as

I establish filename base on file content (first paragraph).
When user click on ribbon file>Save As I want to prompt proper file name (even there is other name). How to handle and put in file name in window on attached screen? 
[My SaveAs backstage window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CAcO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
  .Name = Split(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

The above code intercepts the Save As dialogue.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve my problem (I already do this like in your code, but my problem is in other window).
Thanks anyway.

Comment: The perhaps you should explain more clearly what the problem is and show us *your* code. Your description referred to "user click on ribbon file>Save As", which is what the macro I posted intercepts, but your screenshot doesn't actually show the SaveAs dialogue...

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot in primary post, I didn't have a dialogue form yet (after clicking File>SaveAs). I don't have any code. I know and use code above (overide FileSave and FileSaveAs procedure) but this is triggered when icon or shortcut is using.